# ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server: mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

I am trying to install mysql 5.7 in ubuntu by executing sudo apt-get install mysql-server but it is giving error:

```
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have given permission to the file specified in the error using `chmod 777` but the error still prevails. What I can do?

Comment: Did you follow the advice given in the message?

Comment: Yes.But nothing worked.